# Is it possible to implement a 'double-jump' feature without the use of html canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm making a game for a project on my course and am wondering how to make a 'character' perform a double-jump(a second mid-air jump). It is an endless-runner game where the player is on a fixed position on the screen and must jump over and slide under obstacles as they appear on the screen. I currently have my jump and slide functions working though they need some fine-tuning to make more precise and fun in use.

I've tried using .stop() to cancel the jump animation and perform another jump.
Here's my code in a jsbin to look at:

http://jsbin.com/yekarel/edit?html,js,output

Really only looking to see if this is possible and how to go about doing it, though any suggestions on tidying up the code is still welcome. Thanks.

Edit: I'm trying to avoid the use of canvas in this project so only really looking for a solution that doesn't involve canvas.

Comment: I'm running the jsbin in Chrome, and the character jumps every time I press the space bar. Press it enough times, and the character will jump higher than the "RUN!" text.  How does this differ from what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to limit the sequential jumps to a maximum of two?

Comment: @MJH I never even realised that was happening. Knowing that now though, yes limiting the sequential jumps to a maximum of two sounds like the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be accomplished by adding `var jumpCount = 0;` to the variable declarations at the beginning, and then making the following changes (in which case you can remove the `doubleJump()` and `fallDown2()` functions):

```
// jump function
$(this).keyup(function(e) {
  if(jumpCount < 2 && (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32)) {
    jumpCount++;
    $($character).animate({ top: '-=120px' }, {
      duration: 350,
      easing: 'linear',
      complete: function() {
        fallDown();
      }
    });
  }
});

function fallDown() {
  $($character).animate({top: '+=120px'}, {
    duration: 180,
    easing: 'linear'
  });
  jumpCount--;
}
```

Comment: That works pretty well, thankyou! All the timings on the animations need a lot of tweaking for it to feel good but you've helped me a lot so thank you @MJH